# How to know when a body completes an orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations, celestial-mechanics

I'm simulating a solar system, and I would like to know when a body, has completed an orbit around another. Is there any specific formula for it?

[image: Example]

As shown in the picture, the orbit is elliptical, with a varying radius. I don't know how to calculate the period, when this happens.

Comment: Search on `Orbital Period`.  Wikipedia has the correct formula.

Comment: @BillWatts - I don't think an analytical formula is appropriate for a simulation. I think the _op_ want the conditions to signify an orbit has happened. Also, this is a great question that requires a good level of understanding of dynamical system to effectively answer it, and I don't understand why people are voting to close it.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou And you don't think a simulation can check the time spent in orbit to see if the orbit has been completed?  That would be the first thing I would try.  The OP asks for a formula for the period.   He is not asking to compute position vs time for the orbit.

Comment: @BillWatts - I was thinking that numerical drift, precession, and a moving barycenter might complicate things. I would look at kinetic energy vs. potential energy and if within a certain tolerance of a previous point in this phase space then and orbit is complete.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Maybe, but the OP mentions none of those.  I think you are talking about solving a problem way more complicated than is contained in the original question.

Comment: @BillWatts - yeah. maybe but _any_ simulation would have numerical drift. So even if the calculated period is $T$, the simulation won't complete an orbit until $T+\Delta T$.

Comment: @John Alexiou - My answer gives a very simple model to start with. From the picture given, it appears that it is currently only a two body problem. However, when the solar system becomes more complicated, you are right that many factors will come into play that will complicate things. I would suggest a recursion plot if things get hairy. This allows an analysis of the periodicity and period of a system with complicated dynamics. It also allows for a specified distance threshold to allow for slight perturbations to the orbit.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a vector from the central body to the orbiting body. An orbit has been completed when this vector points in the same direction as when the simulation started. The orbital period is the time it takes for the objects to return to their original orientation with respect to each other.

In programming terms, let's say the planet has a position $\vec{x}_p$ and the star has a position $\vec{x}_s$. Define a vector $\vec{r} = \vec{x}_p - \vec{x}_s$. The angle of $\vec{r}$ is given by $\theta = \textrm{atan2}(r_y, r_x)$. An orbit has been completed when $\theta$ returns to its original value.

Depending on what information you start with, another way to predict the period is to use [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law):
$$T = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2 a^3}{G(M+m)}}$$
where $T$ is the orbital period, $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit (half the larger width of the ellipse of the orbit, or the average of the closest and farthest distances between the bodies), $G$ is the gravitational constant, and $M$ and $m$ are the masses of the orbiting bodies.

If your starting point is just the position and velocity of the orbiting body, then you'll need the more complicated math found in [Brian Opatosky's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/598789/45164).

Answer (score 4):

For the two-body central force problem, the radial equation is:

$$r(\theta)=\frac{p}{1+e\,cos(\theta - \phi)}$$

where $$\phi$$ is the phase angle, $$\theta$$ is the angle of the satellite object in its orbit, $$p\, \equiv \, \frac{L^2}{Gm^2M}$$

(L is the angular momentum, m is the mass of the satellite, M is the mass of the central body, and G is Newton's gravitational constant), and $$e$$ is the eccentricity for the orbit. For an elliptical orbit:

$$ e\, =\, \sqrt{\frac{2\,E_0\,m\,p^2}{{L_0}^2}\,+\,1}$$

Note that the angular momentum is:

$$\overrightarrow{L_{net}}=\overrightarrow{r} \times \overrightarrow{p}=$$

$$r\,\hat{r} \times m\,  (\dot r \hat{r} + r\,\dot\theta \hat{\theta})=$$

$$m\,r^2\,\dot\theta\,\hat{z}$$

Note that, for *strictly* central force problems:

$$\dot{\overrightarrow{L_{net}}}\,=\,\tau_{net}\,=\, \overrightarrow{r} \times\sum_i\, \overrightarrow{F_i}\,=\, r\,\hat{r}\, \times\, \sum_i\, F_i\, \hat{r}\, =\, \overrightarrow{0} $$

This means that, for a central force problem, the angular momentum is constant. Thus:

$$\dot\theta\, =\, \frac{L_0}{m\,r^2}$$

where $$L_0$$
is that inital angular momentum (or any convenient time).

Thus:

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,=\, \frac{L_0}{m\,r^2}$$

So:

$$\frac{m\,r^2\, d\theta}{L_0}\, =\, dt$$

$$\frac{m}{L_0}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0\,+\,2\pi}\,r^2\,d\theta\,=\,\int_{0}^{T}\, dt$$

where T is the period and the limits of the integral on the left were chosen from any arbitrary angle and the upper limit was is because of the $$2\pi$$ periodicity of the radial function (at the top).

Plugging in the radial equation:

$$\frac{m}{L_0}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0\,+\,2\pi}\,({\frac{p}{1\,+\,e\,cos(\theta-\phi)}})^2\,d\theta\,=\,\int_{0}^{T}\, dt$$

$$\frac{m\,p^2}{L_0}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0\,+\,2\pi}\,[1\,+\,e\,cos(\theta-\phi)]^{-2}\,d\theta\,=\,T$$

Using a change of variables:

$$u \,\equiv\, (\theta\, -\, \phi)\,\,\, \Rightarrow\,\,\,du\,=\, d\theta\, $$and$$\, u_{initial}\,=\, (\theta_0\,-\,\phi) \, $$and$$u_{final}\,=\,(\theta_0\,+\,2\pi\,-\,\phi)$$

The equation then becomes:

$$\frac{m\,p^2}{L_0}\int_{(\theta_0\,-\,\phi)}^{(\theta_0\,+\,2\pi\,-\,\phi)}\,[1\,+\,e\,cos(u)]^{-2}\,du\,=\,T$$

That integral is still pretty nasty... here is the result without the going through it:

$$\left.\left(\frac{e\,sin(u)}{(e^2 -1)\,(e\,cos(u)\,+\,1)}\,-\,\frac{2\,arctanh\left(\frac{(e-1)\,tan(\frac{u}{2})}{\sqrt{e^2 -1}}\right)}{(e^2 -1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\right\vert_{\theta_0\,-\,\phi}^{\theta_0\,+\,2\pi\,-\,\phi}\,=\,\,\,T$$

While this solution is exact... there's a problem. The "function":

$$arctanh(z)$$

is not truly a function, because it is not single-valued. It is a multivalued analytic function. Basically, while the hyperbolic tangent function is a true function, its inverse is not, as single inputs have multiple outputs. To overcome this, something called branch cuts are made and principal values are defined. Put simply, the domain and range of arctanh is restricted so that it behaves like a function. In doing this, a variety of values are neglected. So, in this particular problem, plugging in the arbitrary bounds always yields:

$$T\, =\, 0$$

which is the solution of how long it takes to reach the same point... without moving, which is useless. The more useful period is lost because of the branch cutting. All hope isn't lost though! Instead of using the exact, analytic solution, we can just define the previous integral function as our "period function". The true, useful period can be computed via numerical integration (would highly recommend doing it computationally). I ran a few tests and found Simpson's Rule integration and the Trapezoid method to be highly accurate, though Monte Carlo integration was fairly accurate as well. All that is left is to recognize that the initial angle $$\theta_0$$
and phase angle $$\phi$$ are arbitrary when plugged into the solution, as they will cancel out. Thus, written simpler:

$$T\,=\,\frac{m\,p^2}{L_0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,[1\,+\,e\,cos(u)]^{-2}\,du$$

I hope this helped! Good luck with the project; it sounds awesome.